# Show toolbar icons when CollapsingToolbarLayout collapse

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using CollapsingToolbarLayout in my app and everything working great except displaying toolbar icons when the CollapsingToolbarLayout collapse.These menu items, they are showing correctly when the CollapsingToolbarLayout expand. But getting hide when the CollapsingToolbarLayout collapse. I want to show them even when it is in the collapse position.

[image: Expanded Image]

[image: Collapse Image]

My xml....

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.ViewDetailsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_180sdp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

                <com.tbuonomo.viewpagerdotsindicator.DotsIndicator
                    android:id="@+id/dots_indicator"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:gravity="bottom|center"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    app:dotsColor="@color/white"
                    app:dotsCornerRadius="@dimen/_6sdp"
                    app:dotsSize="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    app:dotsSpacing="@dimen/_2sdp"
                    app:dotsWidthFactor="2"
                    app:progressMode="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullLinearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/_4sdp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:weightSum="3">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="bottom">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/priceTxt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/quicksand_medium"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="bottom">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bedTxt"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="bottom"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/typeTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addressTxt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/_1sdp"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/_2sdp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp">

                <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:id="@+id/details_spin_kit"
                    style="@style/SpinKitView.FadingCircle"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:padding="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    app:SpinKit_Color="@color/colorAccent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                        android:text="Facts"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        tools:fontFamily="@font/raleway" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                        android:baselineAligned="false"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:text="Reference"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:text="RERA permit No."
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:text="Type"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:text="Bedrooms"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:text="Bathrooms"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:text="Price"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:text="Area"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtRef"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtRera"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtType"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtBedRooms"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtBathrooms"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtPrice"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/txtArea"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                                android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                                android:textColor="@color/black"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                    android:text="Amenities"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:fontFamily="@font/raleway" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/amenityRecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                    android:text="About the area"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:fontFamily="@font/raleway" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:weightSum="2">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                            android:text="Region"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                            android:text="City"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                            android:text="District"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />


                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtCity"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtDistrict"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtProvince"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_100sdp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/raleway"
                    android:text="Property description"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_16ssp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    tools:fontFamily="@font/raleway" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_4sdp">

                    <WebView
                        android:id="@+id/descriptionWebView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/commLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_shadow"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/email" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="EMAIL"
                android:textColor="#F84242"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutSms"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/sms" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="SMS"
                android:textColor="#F84242"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutCaller"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_2sdp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:autoLink="phone"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
                android:src="@drawable/call" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="CALL"
                android:textColor="#F84242"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_8ssp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your toolbar

```
 app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

Your toolbar should look like this:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

Comment: Thankz... I had to remove **app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"**